# create project using XTRF REST API

Tags: xtrf

I am unable to find how I can create a project using XTFR REST API. Please help me where I can find the best solution for createProject XTRF REST API functionality.

Answer (score 0):

At present, XTRF doesn't support creating projects via REST API. However, XTRF offers also [WebService API](http://knowledgebase.xtrf.eu/display/XTRFAPIWS), which implements [createProject function](http://knowledgebase.xtrf.eu/display/XTRFAPIWS/Methods#Methods-createProject).

Note that both XTRF REST API and [WebService API](http://knowledgebase.xtrf.eu/display/XTRFAPIWS) is available only for the customers who have purchased access to it.